# Question about The reading of Ibn Abbas in Surah 7:127

Tags: quran, tafseer, qiraat

The Standard reading of surah 7:127 verse 127 is “And the chiefs of Pharaoh’s people said: Do you leave Musa and his people to make mischief in the land and to forsake you and your gods? He said: We will slay their sons and spare their women, and surely we are masters over them”, but Ibn Abbas used to read the verse differently by reading وإلاهتك instead of وآلهتك. Does the reading of Ibn abbas Still mean "Your Ilah"? I have differing things

Comment: Where do you get the claim that ibn 'Abbas read it this way? Please share a source. This reading would mean "your Goddess".